# what does "which" in the sentence indicate?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

There is another way to determine the usage of ‘made of’. If the *material* out of *which* the substance is created has not undergone a change in the process of making the material, then ‘made of‘ can be used.

Does the "which" above indicate the material?

Comment: Yes: "which" refers to "material".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Out of" means:

> indicating the source or derivation of something; from

"Which" is the relative pronoun; it refers to "material". This is due to the "is" being added in "is created".

Comment: "Which" is the relative pronoun; it refers to "material".

Comment: The "which" indicates nothing???

Comment: @Eden0516 Do you understand what a relative pronoun is?

Comment: @gotube Yes I do.

Answer (score 0):

The second *material* should be replaced with **substance** for clarity.

> If the material out of which the substance is created has not undergone a change in the process of making the [substance], then ‘made of‘ can be used.

You are right, and as shown in the other answer *which* has *material* as its referent.